# How to forcibly route audio output to Bluetooth A2DP in iOS?

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

The app needs to record sound through HFP, but play sound through A2DP.

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with:[AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP,  AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers])
```

From what I understand, this will allow me to record and play sound with a bluetooth device that supports both HFP and A2DP. However, when I check the documentation, it says that

> when a single device supports both the Hands-Free Profile (HFP) and
>   the Advanced Audio Distribution Profile (A2DP), the Hands-Free ports
>   will be given a higher priority for routing

So, the recording and playing both routes to HFP, and I can't find a way to force the playing through A2DP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, there is no way to do this currently. I have verified this with Apple.